# How to fetch Calendar Events (exchange server) on SharePoint 2019 onPrem (preferably on spfx webpart)?

Tags: spfx, sharepoint-on-prem, outlook

I want to fetch individual users outlook events on SharePoint 2019 onPrem webpart (i'm using spfx to create webpart).
I am aware it can be done using Graph API on SharePoint Online, but I am trying to do it on SharePoint 2019 onprem. Thanks in advance!